# Cancel child event hierarchy from parent event in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

i have a winforms application and in a part of my code i have one event that inside that event can triger two events, like this:

```
Event 1
  |
  |--> if Event2 != null -> Event 2
  |--> if Event3 != null -> Event 3
```

But in `Event 1`, i have an if that makes a return when the condition is `true`, but my problem is that i don't want to fire `Event 2` or `Event 3`, how can i do it?

Update:

My problem is that even with the `return;` of `Method1`, the `Event2` and/or `Event3` are still triggering

I can show some pseudo-code:

```
private void event1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Method1();
}

private void Method1()
{
   if(condition)
     return;
   //more stuff
}

private void CodeForEvent1()
{
     //some stuff...
     if(Event2 != null)
         Event2(this, new EventArgs());
     if(Event3 !- null)
         Event3(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

**Update 2**:
I will explain better this:
This is a control that has a `textfield` and a `button`, when the button is pressed `Event1` is fired and inside the code of `Event1` are the two calls to `Event2` and `Event3`.
When the button is pressed, a list is showed to load what the user selects inside the textfield. `Event1` is the event that represents the button pressed, `Event2` is the one that represents that the field that the user has selected in the list was loaded in the textfield and `Event3` is the event that is fired when the textfield has changed (when the user changes his selection in the list).
That's why `Event2` and `Event3` are inside `Event1`
Hope to help to understand the workflow.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: In you question more clarification is required ..where is event 2 and even3 3 code which firing ?What you really want

Comment: I have updated my question, hope it helps

Comment: ok now in what condition do you want to cancel event2 and event 3? and in your  pseudo-code you did not call code for event 2 ?

Comment: The condition is in `Method1`, there is a condition that must cancel the call to `Event2` and `Event3` in the method `CodeForEvent1`. `CodeForEvent1` must be executed but no `Event2` and `Event3`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
private void event1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(Method1())
     {
      e.cancel;
      return;
     }
    else
    {
        if(Event2 != null)
     { Event2(this, new EventArgs());}
        if(Event3 != null)
     {Event3(this, new EventArgs());}
    }
}
private void event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // your stuff    
}
private void event3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your stuff
}
private bool Method1()
{
     if(Your_condition_is_Matched)
     {
       return true;

     }
  return false;
}
```